# What were the lights that Leslie Gillis saw in the book Coyote?

Tags: space-exploration, allen-steele

In Allen Steele's book Coyote, Leslie Gillis sees some strange lights on his way to Coyote.

> He concludes from their motion that they are spaceships moving in the opposite direction to Alabama but is it ever explained where those ships came from or if they reached Earth? Given the time it can't have been Glorious Destiny or any of it's sister ships.

Is it explained anywhere in the book or any of its sequels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "spin-off" novels, "Galaxy Blues", "Hex", and "Spindrift" make it clear that it was an alien spacecraft.  I don't have them handy right now to determine which of the three gives the meat and potatoes on them but, yes, it was aliens.